# Modifying a function to use SSE intrinsics

Tags: c++, c++11, floating-point, sse, simd

I am trying to calculate the approximate value of the radical: `sqrt(i + sqrt(i + sqrt(i + ...)))` using SSE in order to get a speedup from vectorization (I also read that the SIMD square-root function runs approximately 4.7x faster than the innate FPU square-root function). However, I am having problems getting the same functionality in the vectorized version; I am getting the incorrect value and I'm not sure

My original function is this:

```
template <typename T>
T CalculateRadical( T tValue, T tEps = std::numeric_limits<T>::epsilon() )
{
    static std::unordered_map<T,T> setResults;

    auto it = setResults.find( tValue );
    if( it != setResults.end() )
    {
        return it->second;
    }

    T tPrev = std::sqrt(tValue + std::sqrt(tValue)), tCurr = std::sqrt(tValue + tPrev);

    // Keep iterating until we get convergence:
    while( std::abs( tPrev - tCurr ) > tEps )
    {
        tPrev = tCurr;
        tCurr = std::sqrt(tValue + tPrev);
    }

    setResults.insert( std::make_pair( tValue, tCurr ) );
    return tCurr;
}
```

And the SIMD equivalent (when this template function is instantiated with `T = float` and given `tEps = 0.0005f`) I have written is:

```
// SSE intrinsics hard-coded function:
__m128 CalculateRadicals( __m128 values )
{
    static std::unordered_map<float, __m128> setResults;

    // Store our epsilon as a vector for quick comparison:
    __declspec(align(16)) float flEps[4] = { 0.0005f, 0.0005f, 0.0005f, 0.0005f };
    __m128 eps = _mm_load_ps( flEps );

    union U {
        __m128 vec;
        float flArray[4];
    };

    U u;
    u.vec = values;

    float flFirstVal = u.flArray[0];
    auto it = setResults.find( flFirstVal );
    if( it != setResults.end( ) )
    {
        return it->second;
    }

    __m128 prev = _mm_sqrt_ps( _mm_add_ps( values, _mm_sqrt_ps( values ) ) );
    __m128 curr = _mm_sqrt_ps( _mm_add_ps( values, prev ) );

    while( _mm_movemask_ps( _mm_cmplt_ps( _mm_sub_ps( curr, prev ), eps ) ) != 0xF )
    {
        prev = curr;
        curr = _mm_sqrt_ps( _mm_add_ps( values, prev ) );
    }

    setResults.insert( std::make_pair( flFirstVal, curr ) );
    return curr;
}
```

I am calling the function in a loop using the following code:

```
long long N;
std::cin >> N;

float flExpectation = 0.0f;
long long iMultipleOf4 = (N / 4LL) * 4LL;
for( long long i = iMultipleOf4; i > 0LL; i -= 4LL )
{
    __declspec(align(16)) float flArray[4] = { static_cast<float>(i - 3), static_cast<float>(i - 2), static_cast<float>(i - 1), static_cast<float>(i) };
    __m128 arg = _mm_load_ps( flArray );
    __m128 vec = CalculateRadicals( arg );

    float flSum = Sum( vec );
    flExpectation += flSum;
}

for( long long i = iMultipleOf4; i < N; ++i )
{
    flExpectation += CalculateRadical( static_cast<float>(i), 0.0005f );
}

flExpectation /= N;
```

I get the following outputs for input `5`:

```
With SSE version: 2.20873
With FPU verison: 1.69647
```

Where does the discrepancy come from, what am I doing wrong in the SIMD equivalent?

---

EDIT: I've realized that the `Sum` function is relevant here:

```
float Sum( __m128 vec1 )
{
    float flTemp[4];
    _mm_storeu_ps( flTemp, vec1 );
    return flTemp[0] + flTemp[1] + flTemp[2] + flTemp[3];
}
```

Comment: I wonder, does the `0xF` in your comparison get sign-extended to a value that's different from `0x0F`?

Comment: @BrianCain Changing the value to `0x0F` didn't change the result unfortunately! Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: For robustness this comparison `std::abs( tPrev - tCurr ) > tEps` should probably care about `isnan`.  Probably not your issue here though.

Comment: @BrianCain Yeah, but I decided that the contract could lie with the argument passer; as long as `0 <= tValue <= FL_MAX` isnan shouldn't be an issue right?

Comment: Sure, unless `isnan(tValue)`.  Fair enough that the caller should know if `isnan(tValue)` this function will never return.

Comment: Yeah; I could better improve the safety of the function (throw an invalid_domain exception), but I'm trying to make sure that it's as fast as possible at the moment (and this is just a one use function, rather than a function I'll reuse)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSE intrinsics can be pretty tedious sometimes...

But not here. You just screwed up your loop :

```
for( long long i = iMultipleOf4; i > 0LL; i -= 4LL )
```

I doubt it's doing what you expected. If `iMultipleOf4` is 4, then your function will compute with 4,3,2,1 but not 0. And then your 2nd loop redo the computation with 4.

The two function give the same results for me, and the loops gives the same `flExpectation` after correction. Though there still is a small difference, probably because the FPUs have slight differences in how they compute.

Comment: Thank you very much; this does seem to fix my problem! However; I am curious as to why there is such a sizeable difference in the values, I didn't expect there to be differences in the first 5 significant figures; do you know if there's anything I can do to help rectify this? (I need a solution accurate to 10^-3)?

Comment: @Shaktal I checked what really happens (on my machine), and it seems that `std::sqrt` is using non-vectored double precision SSE to compute. You SSE code use vectored single precision, so it's possible that you get less precise results. The only way to match the computations is probably to use double precision.

Comment: @Shaktal Not really related to your problem, CPUs since 2011 have AVX instructions, which enable 256-bit wide vectors, instead of the 128-bit you are using. If you want to use it, you should check for AVX support at runtime. Also, in 2015, new CPUs will support AVX-512.

Comment: So are you saying that `std::sqrt` will convert the `float` values I pass to it to `double` and then use an internal double-precision `sqrt` FPU function and then convert back?

Comment: @Shaktal Yes. When I compiled your code, the assembly was loading the float into SSE register, convert to double, SSE double sqrt, then convert to single. This can probably vary between compilers, versions and architecture, but that's what I got. (I used VS2013 on Windows 8.1 amd64)